# Why are stuck threads other than contention ,like slow IO , slow backends (DB queries, web services, rmi calls)?

Tags: weblogic, thread-dump

I am trying to figure out what are the main reasons for stuck thread . Now in WebLogic Server diagnoses a thread as stuck if it is continually working (not idle) for a set period of time. And if a user wants he/she can tune a server's thread detection behavior by changing the length of time before a thread is diagnosed as stuck (Stuck Thread Max Time), and by changing the frequency with which the server checks for stuck threads. My analysis is it is either cause by contention or different reasons like  slow IO , slow backends (DB queries, web services, rmi calls) … rarely it is caused by bad coding or huge data (infinite lops) .

Other than above reasons are there more reasons for a thread to stuck ?

Answer (score 1):

not sure what your question is here, here's my 2 cents

- Bad Coding can lead to stuck threads

  - say a developer using a singleton map or hash etc that all servlets need to access.. when you have high load it can lead to contention for that resource and lead to stuck threads easily.
- Stuck threads can be caused by slow running server (high cpu)
- Sometimes bugs in WLS can cause it to be busy with internal processes resulting in stuck threads.. like WLS stuck in cluster communication.
- You can even have stuck thread when Admin server is waiting to hear from a managed server that failed..

The list can go on and on. Only by taking 3-4 thread dumps in a short span of time can one confirm the cause.

Comment: Can you provide some common patterns or issues which cause a thread to stuck with example ?